# Polymorphic belongs-to relationships in SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm working with a database from a Rails project and am trying to build a Flask application on top of it.

There are some polymorphic associations in there which I can't figure out how to replicate using Flask-SQLAlchemy.

For example, there is a "Photo" model with the attributes `id`, `url`, `photoable_id`, `photoable_type`, and it may belong to an `Artist`, `Organization`, or an `Event`. In the database I have, the `Artist`, `Organization`, and `Event` tables have no references to the photos.

I found [this approach](https://github.com/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/blob/7393ee8d4f20e84240623bb180681742813dd178/examples/generic_associations/discriminator_on_association.py) for polymorphic associations in SQLAlchemy but it requires creating an association table - is there a way to do it with the schema as-is?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What I was looking for is [outlined here](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/_modules/examples/generic_associations/generic_fk.html).

Here's an example for a one-to-many relationship:

```
from app import db
from datetime import datetime
from sqlalchemy import event, and_
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship, foreign, remote, backref


class HasPhotos():
    pass

class Photo(db.Model):
    __tablename__   = 'photos'
    id              = db.Column(db.Integer(), primary_key=True)
    image           = db.Column(db.String())
    photoable_id    = db.Column(db.Integer())
    photoable_type  = db.Column(db.String(50))
    created_at      = db.Column(db.DateTime(), default=datetime.utcnow)
    updated_at      = db.Column(db.DateTime(), default=datetime.utcnow)

    @property
    def parent(self):
        return getattr(self, 'parent_{}'.format(self.photoable_type))



@event.listens_for(HasPhotos, 'mapper_configured', propagate=True)
def setup_listener(mapper, class_):
    name = class_.__name__
    type = name.lower()
    class_.photos = relationship(Photo,
                        primaryjoin=and_(
                                        class_.id == foreign(remote(Photo.photoable_id)),
                                        Photo.photoable_type == type
                                    ),
                        backref=backref(
                                'parent_{}'.format(type),
                                primaryjoin=remote(class_.id) == foreign(Photo.photoable_id)
                                )
                        )
    @event.listens_for(class_.photos, 'append')
    def append_photo(target, value, initiator):
        value.photoable_type = type
```

Then when defining a class to have this relationship, just inherit from `HasPhotos`, e.g.

```
class Artist(HasPhotos, db.Model):
    pass
```

To do a one-to-one relationship, just add the keyword argument `uselist=False` to the `relationship()` call, and instead of listening for the `append` event, listen for the `set` event, e.g.:

```
@event.listens_for(class_.photo, 'set')
def set_photo(target, value, old_value, initiator):
    value.photoable_type = type
```

Comment: Thank you so much for sharing this with everyone! I'm also coming from Rails world and it was really difficult for me to find how to do this kind of polymorphic relationship with SQLAlchemy